# Alert and Prompt in JavaScript are always being executed before anything else

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, alert, ecmascript-5, execution

Hello guys I am facing a weird problem while programming is JavaScript (No wonder! its JS). Well so the 
problem is alert, confirm or prompt are always getting executed before anything else I mean even before the page is loading no matter where I write them.
If I code like this:

document.write("Hello World");

prompt("Enter your name: ");

still the prompt() is executed before document.write().
I know there is a way to control this by using function and calling it on button press. But can you guys suggest me any other simpler way to control this cuz I am really newbie to JS so....

THIS IS MY CODE:

[image]

Actually the task my teacher gave me is to:

1) Create an array of color names

2) Display it on HTML

3) Take input of another color through prompt

4) Add color from input at start of array

5) Display the updated array on HTML again

**Now what is happening is when I am opening my HTML file in which I linked this script immediately asks me for the input of color (prompt on line:4) even before the loading I mean without displaying the default array on HTML page. When I enter the color the page fully loads and shows me default array as well as updated array. But I don't want it to work like that I have to get input after displaying the default array.**

Comment: Please provide us some code that you've tried so far, to better understand your problem

Comment: added code in question that I have tried

Comment: Welcome yo SO! Please copy/paste your code to the question instead of screenshots. Read [ask], and [why this is a problem](//idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)